# Canvas drawimage() black result

Tags: image, canvas, drawimage

I have a large image to draw in a canvas : 1900px X 7000px

80% it loads right, but 20% I have a black canvas instead of my image.
Seems to be the Gpu, but not sure.

Do I have to split this img in two or three, or it won't change anything.

it's just a background image, without requestanimationframe on it.

just drawimage(bg, width, height, 0, 0)

Comment: How about some code and a reference to the large image :)

Comment: Check your syntax - it's supposed to be `drawImage(bg,0,0,width,height)`.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a `load` event listener so that you know if the image has been loaded or not, and call `drawImage` only when it has been loaded. Can't tell you much else without some code or a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this somewhere in your code

```
canvas.toDataURL()
```

use this instead:

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')
```